# System.OutOfMemoryException: "Недостаточно памяти."

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как решается подобное исключение ?

Делаю просто маленький скриншот и вот такая беда(

1 раз сработал как надо, а теперь всегда ловлю это исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".jpg";
    Byte[] byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(byteArray));
    Rectangle croppedImage = new Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);
    screenshot = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat);
    screenshot.Save(String.Format(@"C:\SeleniumScreenshots\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg));
}
```

**UPD:** Скриншоты с данными в переменной `Bitmap screenshot`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншоты с данными в переменной `Rectangle croopedImage`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У тебя походу неправильный rectangle передается. Посмотри какие x,y,w,h передаешь, сверь их с bitmap'овскими w,h и подумай еще раз чего ожидаешь от метода clone.
MDSN - OutOfMemoryException - rectangle выходит за пределы границы исходного растрового изображения.

Comment: @ДжонСмит это копия кода с интернета. Как правильно тогда ? Цель - делать скриншот элемента.

Comment: @ДжонСмит Исключение видимо из за того , что Y выходит за пределы Битмапа - верно ?

Comment: Да, думаю выходит, за пределы размера битмапа. Нужно сделать проверку и валидацию, и вообще подумать почему такие кривые данные приходят в IWebElement'е.

Comment: @ДжонСмит Оказывается что ChromeDriver не делает скриншот полной страницы... , в отличии от других браузеров , а только ту часть окна - в которой находится, а координаты элемента берутся относительно всего документа.